# Android Cannot Resolve Constructor on TimePickerDialog

Tags: android, android-timepicker

Please help me to work my code. I'm getting error like this

```
error: no suitable constructor found for TimePickerDialog(MyHttpPostProjectActivity,<anonymous OnTimeSetListener>,int,int)
constructor TimePickerDialog.TimePickerDialog(Context,int,OnTimeSetListener,int,int,boolean) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor TimePickerDialog.TimePickerDialog(Context,OnTimeSetListener,int,int,boolean) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

startTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            startTimeField.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
        }
    }, hour, minute);        
    startTimePicker.show();
```

Comment: try adding false after minute. minute, false

Comment: false means you dont use 24 hours view. make it true if you want to use it

Answer (score 0):

put one more parameter as false

```
startTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
        startTimeField.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
    }
}, hour, minute, false);        
startTimePicker.show();
```